# Insert an image into a pdf in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Does anyone know how to insert an image into a PDF with **Ruby**?

I have been searching on the internet for some time, but most of the gems do not support the requirement.

The image should be inserted into an existing PDF with content. The content should not be removed. May be you can say inserting an image overlay in the PDF.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Maybe use a gem? https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn

Answer (score 2):

Resolved!!, able to **insert an image into an existing PDF having content** using `hexapdf` gem

Here is the [code sample](https://gist.github.com/aashish/f472f62ce0202eae8a33c2531649f5d6).

Please feel free review and comment.

Answer (score 1):

[Prawn PDF](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) does.

Here is a snippet:

```
pdf.image("./avatar.jpg", at: [180, 680], width: 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem Prawn, which provides a DSL for PDF generation.

Simply put `gem 'prawn', '~> 2.1'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install` and you're done.

```
Prawn::Document.generate("mydocument.pdf", :page_layout => :landscape) do     
  pigs = "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/images/pigs.jpg" 
  image pigs, :at => [50,450], :width => 450                                      

  dice = "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/images/dice.png"
  image dice, :at => [50, 450], :scale => 0.75
 end
```

The [Prawn::Images module](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Images.html) documentation will be useful for you.

Comment: @vnhrs This wont work because, it will create a new PDF or remove existing content from PDF. Which it should not.